# Sudoku in Technicolor!

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

---

This puzzle consists of three overlapping Sudokus, coloured red, blue and green, so each cell will contain three digits, one of each colour. Taken individually, the digits of each colour will form a Sudoku in the grid. In addition, the coloured Sudokus are mutually orthogonal: for each pair of distinct colours A and B and each pair of (possibly equal) digits x and y, there is a unique cell containing an A-coloured x and a B-coloured y. An accepted solution will provide the answer as well as the key logical steps needed to reach it. I hope you enjoy!

[image: Grid]

#### TEXT/COLORBLIND VERSION

**RED CLUES**

```
-------------------
|8| | | | | | | |3|
-------------------
| |3| | | | | |2| |
-------------------
|4| |2| | | |8| |6|
-------------------
| |8| |2| |7| |3| |
-------------------
| | |1| |5| |7| | |
-------------------
| | | | | | | | | |
-------------------
| |5| |7| |4| |1| |
-------------------
|9| |3| |8| |2| |4|
-------------------
| |4| | | | | |6| |
-------------------
```

**BLUE CLUES**

```
-------------------
| | | |1| |2| | | |
-------------------
|1| | | |9| | | |6|
-------------------
| |9| | | | | |2| |
-------------------
| | |7| | | |9| | |
-------------------
| | | |5| |9| | | |
-------------------
| | | | |7| | | | |
-------------------
| | | | | | | | | |
-------------------
| |2| |9| |8| |7| |
-------------------
|9| |8| |3| |4| |2|
-------------------
```

**GREEN CLUES**

```
-------------------
| |7| | | | | |9| |
-------------------
| | |6| | | |7| | |
-------------------
| | | |5| |7| | | |
-------------------
|8| | | |5| | | |4|
-------------------
|7|5| | | | | |3|9|
-------------------
| |2|4|3| |9|1|5| |
-------------------
|4| |2| |3| |5| |1|
-------------------
| | | | | | | | | |
-------------------
| | | |4| |2| | | |
-------------------
```

**SOLVER NOTE**

As clued, the individually coloured Sudokus do not have unique solutions; the mutual orthogonality condition is vital to creating a unique solution to the entire puzzle.

Comment: Slightly confused about the mutually orthogonal part, to clarify, say there is a red 8 and a blue 6, the blue 8 and the red 6 are in the same place on the grid?

Comment: Not quite. If there is a red 8 and blue 6 in one cell, there will be no other cell with this combination. However, there will be a cell with a red 6 and blue 8, necessarily elsewhere, in the grid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<sub>Should've known what I'd gotten myself into when starting, *whew*. Great puzzle! Really hard, but I hope I got everything right.</sub>

---

0th Step: Try to squeeze out everything we can by normal Sudoku first:

> [image]
>
>  This blocks `g4b9`, `g6b2`, `g5b8` and `r1g1`

1st Step:

> G R5C5 and G R2C2  must be 4 because `g4b9` is blocked. G R9C1 must be 5 because `g5b8` is blocked. This gives us R1C6 = 4, G R1C3 = 5, G R2C9 = 5, G R2C6 = 3, G R4C6 = 1 by normal Sudoku. New pairs: `r5g4`, `r3g4`, `g5b9`, `g4b2`, `g5b6`, `r7g1`
>
>  With `g4b2`, G R3C7 must also be 4, which gives us G R8C8 = 4 by normal Sudoku. These add the pairs `r8g4` and `g4b7` to the collection.
>
>  [image]

2nd Step:

> B R9C4 can only be 6 or 7 by Sudoku, but since `g4b7` is blocked, it must be 6. R R8C8 is either 5 or 7 by Sudoku, but must be 7 because of `r5g4`. This gives us R R2C9 = 7 New pairs: `g4b6`, `r7g4`, `r7b7`, `r7g5`, `r7b6`, `r7b8`
>
>   Now R R9C3 must be 7 because of the new `r7g5`. Now some normal Sudoku logic for box 4, 7, 9 and 5. R R4C9 must be 1, it can't be 5 since `r5g4`. R R6C9 in turn is 5. R R9C4 must be 9. Added `r8g2`, `r9g1`, `r3g5`, `r5b4`, `r8b2`, `r2g9`, `r1g4`, `r3g7`, `r7g6`, `r2g2`
>
>  R R9C4 must actually be 9, because 1 is blocked by `r1g4` **and** 3 is blocked by `r3g4`! Of course this adds `r9g4` and `r9b6` to the blacklist.
>
>  [image]

3rd step:

> G R4C4 cannot be 2 because of `r2g2`, the only place where 2 can go in G box 5 is G R5C4, giving an additional pair `g2b5`. G R5C7 must be 8 because of `r7g6`. Now some Sudoku logic for green, giving us additional pairs of `r2g7`, `r6b9`, `g8b7`, `r4b8`, `r1g7`
>
>  G R4C7 must be 2 since 6 is blocked by the newly added `r6b9`. G R7C4 is 9 because 6 is blocked by `r7g6`. Now Sudoku rules on G R7C2, G R4C8 and G R9C8. New pairs: `g2b9`, `r7g9`, `r5g6`, `r3g6`, `r6g8`.
>
>  [image]

Last step:

> At this point I'm going to leave out the pair listing and reasons, since it gets repetitive. The basic idea is to keep a list of all used pairs and remove possible candidates from a cell if it appears in one of them, after that you can *basically* apply normal Sudoku on it.
>
>   The rest of the green grid can be solved now (but not entirely by Sudoku logic):
>  [image]
>
>  And then also the red one:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Obviously we now already have a pairing for each blue cell, so we can also finish the blue grid if we just have the patience :)
>
>   [image]

Comment: Damn I was about halfway through, good job! :P This was very hard so great answer!

Comment: More or less correct, but there is a typo in the red grid, upper middle square...you have two 9s. I checked everything else though, and it is just a typo. Great job! I hope you enjoyed.

Comment: @JeremyDover Whoops, fixed that. Must've happened in the rush when I realized that now is not the best time to get sniped :P Yes, it was very enjoyable!