# Orthogonal Sudokus

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

This a Sudoku puzzle created by [Paul Vaderlind](http://forum.enjoysudoku.com/orthogonal-sudoku-t1568.html).

Fill each cell with 2-digit numbers from 11 to 99 (without the digit 0) such that

- The first digits represent one regular Sudoku grid.
- The second digits represent another regular Sudoku grid.
- Each number from 11 to 99 (without the digit 0) occurs exactly once in the grid (orthogonality constraint). So "23" cannot occur twice, but "23" and "32" both occur.

[image]

For your convenience I also made a version where the first digits have been replaced by letters from A to I.

[image]

Comment: I was going to find my own pair of such Sudokus, but then I was pleasantly surprised that someone has already done it. Interestingly you can find a set of 7 Sudokus that are all pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106798) features a triplet of mutually orthogonal Sudokus, for any who may be interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with the same answer as @Dr Xorile:

> [image: Finished Sudokus]

This one was actually pretty easy to do by hand in a spreadsheet. However it took enough steps that I couldn't undo all the way back to the beginning, so the first few steps are just going to be what I remember doing. I'll try to recreate the first part later when I have some time:

> The first and most helpful thing I did after transcribing the puzzle was create a chart of all the numbers used so far. The extra information I could see in the chart made it a lot easier to decide what to try to figure out next.

> My next step was just to look at each Sudoku individually and use very basic solving techniques. That allowed me to find all the 9_s and some others.

As soon as that was no longer bearing fruit:

> I decided to look at the orthogonality constraint. Using my chart of used numbers, I could see that the 1_s didn't have too many left. By looking at the possibility for each 1_, I was able to solve for all of them.

More groups:

> Next up were the 8_s, 9_s, and _9s, though I don't remember the order in which I did them. I think the 9_s were first.

(I have some pictures for this point on!) I was able to make a lot of progress on the second-digit Sudoku at this point

> I was able to find all the _5s and some of the _3s:
>  [image: _5s done and _3s progress]

Another set of numbers finished:

> I figured out the rest of the _3's and got 44 and 68 along the way.
>  [image: Pretty easy from here]
>  It was at about this point that I didn't really have to look very hard for the next number to fill in. Just normal sudoku rules for rows, columns, and cells, using the chart of used numbers as a guide for where to aim next and quickly narrowing down possibilities.

Finally, almost done:

> I got to this point and saw that it looked underconstrained, and finally noticed that I'd missed transcribing a clue. Trivial to solve from here once I put it in
>  [image: Almost there]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is:

> 59  23  96  18  42  75  84  61  37
>  88  62  35  57  21  94  16  43  79
>  17  41  74  89  63  36  55  22  98
>  26  99  53  45  78  12  67  34  81
>  65  38  82  24  97  51  49  76  13
>  44  77  11  66  39  83  28  95  52
>  93  56  29  72  15  48  31  87  64
>  32  85  68  91  54  27  73  19  46
>  71  14  47  33  86  69  92  58  25

I saw a recent comment on a different question about linear programming, so decided to give it a go. It was harder than I thought, but mostly me figuring out the syntax etc. I thought of trying by hand, but the orthogonality constraint is a pain to spot by eye. I might give it a go with a spreadsheet like I did with the mobius sudoku, where the spreadsheet can track those sorts of details.

Comment: I was halfway there doing it on hand :)

Comment: Ah, another job lost to the machines. Where will it end?

Comment: I've got to say, its really tedious with hand... If I remembered that computers was a thing...

Comment: If it's any consolation, it took me a ludicrous amount of time to code (aka debug / understand), and the code ran for a while. And was somewhat unsatisfying because it's a black-box...

Comment: I don't agree with the minuses, because this is a perfectly valid approach. I never said that computers are not allowed. I can imagine it takes considerable effort to program a constraint solver.

Comment: I did check that the no-computer tag wasn't there before I did it.